# How to include selected email body in Outlook 2010 custom form?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I have a custom form that users will use when they receive a certain email. I have the VBA to select the email and forward it, but I cannot figure out how to include the forwarded email within the custom form's email body.

---

**UPDATE: For any lost soul trying to accomplish this, I've found a solution to my problem.**

```
Sub CustomForm_IncludesSelectedEmailBody()

Dim myOlApp As Application
Dim myNameSpace As NameSpace
Dim myFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim myItems As Items
Dim myItem As Object
Dim origEmail As MailItem


Set origEmail = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = _
    myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)
Set myItems = myFolder.Items
Set myItem = myItems.Add("IPM.Note.DL_MALC_R_V1")
'the "IPM.Note.DL_MALC_R_V1" is the custom form's file name


myItem.HTMLBody = origEmail.Forward.HTMLBody
'this attaches the body of the email you're viewing to your new, forwarded email
myItem.Subject = origEmail.Forward.Subject
'This includes the selected email's subject line in your new email.
myItem.To = "emailYouWantToSendTo@example.com"
myItem.Display

Set myOlApp = Nothing
Set myNameSpace = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
Set myItems = Nothing
Set myItem = Nothing
Set CustomForm = Nothing

End Sub
```

**To create a button for running the VBA, that's as simple as customizing the ribbon and selecting the macro to run from there.**

/End Updated Answer

---

Essentially what I want to happen is:

1. The user clicks a button which loads my custom form
2. Upon the button click in step 1, the selected or viewed email is included in the custom form's email body.

My thinking was that I would combine the 2 code sections below with the following

```
Sub Combined()
    RunMyForm
    Forward
    'gets the forwarded email in the Forward sub, but doesnt include the body of the forwarded email in the custom form.
End Sub
```

and that it would work, but that isn't happening. I'm very new to VBA so I'm sure I'm missing something here.

Creating the button isn't the problem, as that's easy to do within Outlook itself. I listed the 2 code sections from the **Sub Combined()** below.

1. VBA to pull the custom form.

```
Sub RunMyForm()
  Dim myOlApp As Application
  Dim myNameSpace As NameSpace
  Dim myFolder As MAPIFolder
  Dim myItems As Items
  Dim myItem As Object

  Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set myFolder = _
    myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)
  Set myItems = myFolder.Items
  Set myItem = myItems.Add("IPM.Note.Test1")
  myItem.Display

  Set myOlApp = Nothing
  Set myNameSpace = Nothing
  Set myFolder = Nothing
  Set myItems = Nothing
  Set myItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

2. Selecting the currently viewed item, forwarding it, and forwarding it to a specific email address.

```
Sub Forward()
'Combined with function GetcurrentItem, this forwards the selected email
    Dim fwd As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim itm As Object

    Set itm = GetCurrentItem()
    If Not itm Is Nothing Then
        Set fwd = itm.Forward
        fwd.Recipients.Add "email@exampleemail.com"
        fwd.Display
    End If

    Set fwd = Nothing
    Set itm = Nothing
End Sub
Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application

    Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        Case Else
            ' anything else will result in an error, which is
            ' why we have the error handler above
    End Select

    Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Where in the custom form? can we see how your form looks like?

Comment: Should you not have `Set GetCurrentItem = Nothing` in the *Case Else*? If this macro is run within Outlook, no need to Create Outlook Application Object.

Comment: 0m3r, would a screenshot suffice for the custom form? Or do you need a more in depth look at the form for html code reasons?

Comment: PatricK, good catch, I'll change it to that. I don't think that's why it is preventing the combination of the two macros though, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Posting down here so I can mark the question as answered. Sorry, I'm new to Stackoverflow.)

**UPDATE: For any lost soul trying to accomplish this, I've found a solution to my problem.**

```
Sub CustomForm_IncludesSelectedEmailBody()

Dim myOlApp As Application
Dim myNameSpace As NameSpace
Dim myFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim myItems As Items
Dim myItem As Object
Dim origEmail As MailItem


Set origEmail = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = _
    myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)
Set myItems = myFolder.Items
Set myItem = myItems.Add("IPM.Note.CustomForm1")
'the "IPM.Note.CustomForm1" is the custom form's file name


myItem.HTMLBody = origEmail.Forward.HTMLBody
'this attaches the body of the email you're viewing to your new, forwarded email
myItem.Subject = origEmail.Forward.Subject
'This includes the selected email's subject line in your new email.
myItem.To = "emailYouWantToSendTo@example.com"
myItem.Display

Set myOlApp = Nothing
Set myNameSpace = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
Set myItems = Nothing
Set myItem = Nothing
Set CustomForm = Nothing

End Sub
```